# How to save the values in existing input fields when adding a new one?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, input

This is what my program's body looks like:

```
<form id = "input">
<input id = "0" >
</form>

<p onclick = "add()"> Add Another</p>
```

And on clicking the above

The following function is executed:

```
 var inputArea = document.getElementById("input");
        next = 1;
    function add(){

        inputArea.innerHTML+= "  <input id = " + next+ ">" ;
```

Where next is the id of new input field. In this case, since 0 already exists so value of `next` is 1. 
One problem that I am encountering with this is that after adding a new input field, the values in all existing input fields are lost. How to save these values?  My attempt is to place this code in function add():

```
    for (i=0;i<next;i++)
    {inputs[i] = document.getElementById(i);
    inputV[i]= inputs[i].value;
inputs[i].value = inputV[i];}
```

But this does not works..

```js
      var inputArea = document.getElementById("input");
            next = 1;
        function add(){
            
            inputArea.innerHTML+= "  <input id = " + next+ ">" ;
       var inputs = new Array();
       var inputV = new Array();
       for (i=0;i<next;i++)
            {inputs[i] = document.getElementById(i);
            inputV[i]= inputs[i].value;
        inputs[i].value = inputV[i];}

        next++;
        }
```

```html
<form id = "input">
        <input id = "0" >
        </form>
       
        <p onclick = "add()"> Add Another</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to dynamically add elements to your DOM tree like so

```
function add() {
    var form = document.getElementById("input");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

The problem with what you're doing is that when you write inside an `input` field, the changes are not represented in the HTML code, only in the memory of the browser. Thus if you add text through to code to `form.innerHTML`, the browser is going to reinterpret the text inside the form which will be

```
<input id="0"> <input id="1"> ...
```

and this will result in two empty `input` of type text being displayed.

Edit: you can then add your id tag via

```
function add() {
    var form = document.getElementById("input");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.id = someValue;
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

*N.B. please indent your code in a somewhat logical manner.*

Comment: Ah yeah.. I will take care of note from next time!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is that the dom, or more specifically `inputArea`'s innerHtml doesnt get changed when you type into a form field. And what youre doing is resetting the innerHTML with a blank input BEFORE youre capturing the values.

so whats going on is you have HTML like this:

```
<input id='0' />
```

then type into the form so that it behaves like:

```
<input id='0' value='foo' />
```

but thats not what the innerHTML actual is. its still `<input id='0' />` because the value is kept in memory not on the dom.

if you want to add new elements to the form, you need to use `appendChild` instead

so convert

```
inputArea.innerHTML+= "  <input id = " + next+ ">"
```

to

```
inputArea.appendChild(document.createElement('input'))
```